# Query String ignore symbol

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value in my query string using this function

```js
  const getQueryStringValueByName = name => {
    name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    let url = window.location.href;
    let regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    
    results = regex.exec(url);
    
    if (!results) return null;
    
    if (!results[2]) return "";
    
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  };
```

Its working properly but when the value has `&` it cuts up the whole value like this one

`ViewName=MyValue%20&%202ndString&FilteringColumn=OriginatingGroup`

what I am getting is only

`MyValue`

I was expecting to get

`MyValue & 2ndString`

Comment: Made a revision to your code formatting for the sake of readability.

Comment: Is every query separated by %20? or in the format of Something%20SomethingElse%AnotherThing?

Comment: `&` in values should be escaped - replaced with `%26`. suggested example isn't really correct

Comment: %20 is supposed to be "space"

Comment: Since `&` is the separator between parameters, you need to encode it in hex if you want to use it in a parameter itself.

Comment: The same thing with `=`.